# Does Javascript accept a path in getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom

I have been looking around for an answer on this question : should the following snippet work ?

```
getElementsByTagName("parent/child/grand-child");
```

For a structure like this :

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <grand-child></grand-child>
  </child>
</parent>
```

My specific problem is that it works in the development environment, and once in production doesn't and I get the message "This name may not contain '/' character."

If getElementsByTagName is supposed to work with a path like this, I would need ideas about a possible cause of this problem.

Comment: You should take a look at [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/QuerySelector)

Comment: Try to use `querySelectorAll('parent child grand-child')`.

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan: This can skip a generation. Should rather use `>` operators like dystroy, or XPath.

Comment: You can use `document.evaluate` and specify an XPath expression, which gives you the ability for more complex searches, such as `parent/child[1]/grand-child`.

Comment: @Amadan You're right, this will skip a generation, but it is not mentioned in the question, so both are correct in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) only accepts a tag name.

But you can use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` with a CSS selector :

```
var element = document.querySelector("parent child grand-child");
```

or

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("parent > child > grand-child");
```

Comment: Nope. `querySelectorAll` is newish. There are polyfills, like [this](https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/8960575). It will be slow though.

Comment: [`querySelector` is supported since IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), and older IEs than 8 are almost extinct by now.

Comment: True. Thanks. I think my target is IE8 actually.

Answer (score 1):

No. `getElementsByTagName` gets elements by *tag name*, not by their path. Use XPath for paths: `document.evaluate` (IE, again, does it differently), or use CSS selectors with `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll`.